# Visualizing Data on a Mac? (MySQL db is source)

Tags: ms-office, mysql, graph

I'm having difficulty finding a promising OS X app for connecting to and visualizing data which resides in a MySQL database; it seems like there are various options for Windows, but not so much for Apple?

I'm hoping however that there are some gems that I just haven't discovered yet

I would like to be able to publish these charts to the web; I have heard of people using Excel for this, but I don't own Excel for Mac and I'm not sure if the same abilities are present in the Mac version of it

Comment: What package does what you need on windows? Since office 365 if free for a month and you can try it out quite readily. Also, unix based plotting is rich, free and well documented. Have a look at [posts like this](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2013/12/simple-plotting-from-the-command-line/) and packages like [mathplotlib](http://matplotlib.org).

Answer (score 2):

OpenOffice and derivatives like [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/base/) and [NeoOffice](http://neowiki.neooffice.org/index.php/NeoBase) can connect to a MySQL DB using [ODBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODBC); and, once the connection is established, the spreadsheet component can use it as a data source.

Answer (score 0):

There is R, with gui Rstudio, or tableau, but as @bmike says, depends on what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [Ubiq](http://ubiq.co). It is a web based data visualization tool for MySQL. It supports MySQL database on Mac.

Answer (score -1):

You can go for Navicat for MySQL/Premium (Mac) and Sequel Pro. They can help you to connect and visualise your data.

- http://www.sequelpro.com
- http://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-premium